# Why VS2017 debugging will not stop at dllmain breakpoint?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winapi, dll, visual-studio-debugging

I'm building a dll for the first time and everything is working as expected but I cannot debug it.

I made the most minimal example possible, of just a dllmain() and set the project up using the wizard for windows DLL (non-MFC).

active build configuration: x86 debug

right clicked project -> Set as startup project

disabled precompiled headers

project properties -> debugging -> command -> entered path of the application executable

Generate Debug Info is yes

This is the entire DLL, no  other source or header files.  When I press F5 the application runs and loads the dll, the messagebox triggers.  If the debugbreak is uncommented the messagebox doesn't trigger and the DLL does nothing but does Load successfully.  The debugger does not break.  If a breakpoint is used, it does not break.

The application is definitely loading the DLL I am building.

The .pdb file is there and being generated.

I tried changing the debugger to mixed, auto, native, it still isn't working.  The CALLING application is probably written in C#, but it's not mine.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
// Windows Header Files
#include <windows.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{

//  __debugbreak();

    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hit DLLMAIN", "test", MB_OK);

    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

I did a lot of research but I can't figure out why it wont debug.

Update: I wrote a program to call LoadLibrary on the DLL and modified my project to call that program as the command.

It went into the debugger just fine.  Even when I changed the loader program to a release configuration.

Whatever the issue is it may be caused by the third party program loads the dll.

Edit: this is the debug console output when trying to debug my dll with the third party program, it seems that the debugger exits for some reason though the program continues running.

```
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Tech1\AppData\Local\ProgramDir\Program.exe'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Private_API.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Program.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x4610 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2614 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x45c0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[21792] Program.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Using MessageBox to debug code is a bad idea.  It is formally illegal to use it in DllMain(), if user32.dll isn't loaded yet then your program will deadlock.  Using NULL as the first argument is trouble, a dialog requires an owner window to be on top of and if it can't find one that the desktop becomes the owner.  Making it likely that you can't see it because it is overlapped by another window.  And randomly do see it when debugbreak() causes focus changes.  You do need to get the debugger breakpoint working to make any real headway, lots of existing questions about that.

Comment: @HansPassant I got the debugger working by writing a program to load the dll and using that.  I agree about MB().  I'm starting to use AllocConsole with freopen stdout, but trying to get the DLL entry/exit straightened out so I am not repeatedly allocating or opening.  What do you think could be preventing VS from debugging via the third party application?

Comment: @HansPassant - *if user32.dll isn't loaded yet then your program will deadlock.* - even if *user32.dll* not loaded yet - program will **not** deadlock. load dll inside loader lock **never deadlock** because our thread already owner this loader lock. deadlock can be only if we begin **wait** say for another thread and this thread try enter to loader lock.

Comment: @user10530562 Interestingly, I created a program to try to reproduce your situation. I don't know if I understand the error. If the `debugbreak` is uncommented, `debugbreak` will work and trigger a breakpoint reminder, which seems different from what you have encountered.Then I continue, and the program can execute to the `Messagebox`.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT Hey thank you for looking at it.  I took another look at it today and it seems the debugger is detaching immediately after starting, but the program keeps running.  Please see my update to the post.

Comment: @user10530562 Use `LoadLibrary` to load the DLL in a C++ application, it can step into the DllMain using Visual Studio debugger. How do you make the third party program loads your DLL? You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-dll-projects?view=vs-2019) for debugging your DLL.

Answer (score -1):

Not really a definitive answer, but I debug native DLL's all the time and I have a couple of suggestions:

1) If the application that uses the DLL is still live, and you know how to make it attempt to access said DLL again, you can also try "Debug->Attach to Process".

2) Make sure your DLL is not recompiling itself when you hit F5 for debug.  I once had a static library dependency that was causing the DLL to recompile on every debug.  There was also a move step to move the DLL into the target applications executable folder on compile.   This caused the debugger to think I was not using the exact same version of the DLL.  It might have been a timing issue.  If you have a move step, the DLL version must be the exact same compilation.